# Bigquery encrypt/decrypt specific column with own plain text key

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new on bigquery my task is to encrypt only email column in bigquery. I can not use udf there so with query itself i need to implement that but i am not getting any buildin function for doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt the email column on the **client** before storing it in BigQuery. You can then keep your key safely stored elsewhere and never expose plain-text email in the database. This still allows you to look up rows with a particular email address, you just have to send the encrypted blob as part of any query that you want to run.

Note that this still allows someone with access to your database to know which rows had the **same** email address. This may or may not be an issue for you (as I don't know why you need to encrypt the addresses).

If you don't need to be able to reverse the stored email addresses, but just want to be able to compare them, consider storing hashes instead -- you can use the SHA256() function to do this. If you want to make this even more difficult to reverse with a pre-computed lookup table, you might consider salting the hashes as well.

See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

There is currently no way to encrypt your database (or individual columns) with a user-specified key, but you could open a feature request for such a thing on the BigQuery public issue tracker.